# Убрать переносы в атрибуте xml при помощи php

Tags: php, xml

Есть xml файл выгруженный в строку вида

```
<catalog>
  <item id="111" name="Тут может содержаться ; которую не надо заменять" property="Дата;Имя;
  2017-01-01;Ivan;
  2017-02-02;Vova;" />
  <item id="112" name="Тут может содержаться ; которую не надо заменять" property="Дата;Имя;
  2017-01-02;Ivan;
  2017-02-03;Vova;" />
</catalog>
```

Ни как не могу привести код к виду

```
    <catalog>
      <item id="111" name="Тут может содержаться ; которую не надо заменять" property="Дата!тут мой символ1! Имя!тут мой символ1!!тут мой символ2!2017-01-01!тут мой символ1!Ivan!тут мой символ1!!тут мой символ2!2017-02-02!тут мой символ1!Vova!тут мой символ1!" />
      <item id="112" name="Тут может содержаться ; которую не надо заменять" property="Дата!тут мой символ1! Имя!тут мой символ1!!тут мой символ2!2017-01-02!тут мой символ1!Ivan!тут мой символ1!!тут мой символ2!2017-02-03!тут мой символ1!Vova!тут мой символ1!" />
    </catalog>
```

То есть мне необходимо заменить все **переносы строк** на **!тут мой символ2!**, а все **точки с запятой** на **!тут мой символ1!**, но тольк внутри атрибута **property**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с использованием регулярных выражений:

```
<?php

$xml = '<catalog>
  <item id="111" name="Тут может содержаться ; которую не надо заменять" property="Дата;Имя;
  2017-01-01;Ivan;
  2017-02-02;Vova;" />
  <item id="112" name="Тут может содержаться ; которую не надо заменять" property="Дата;Имя;
  2017-01-02;Ivan;
  2017-02-03;Vova;" />
</catalog>';


$symb_1 = '!тут мой символ1!'; // Замена точки с запятой
$symb_2 = '!тут мой символ2!'; // Замена переносов


echo preg_replace_callback(
    '~property="[^"]+"~',
    function ($m) use ($symb_1, $symb_2) {
        if (!empty($m[0])) {
            $patt = ['~;~', "~\n~", '~\s{2,}~'];
            $symb = [$symb_1, $symb_2, null];
            return preg_replace($patt, $symb, $m[0]);
        }
    },
    $xml
);
```

Comment: @Roman Gorbunoff запостил ответ.